# Oracle SQL - Joins Syntax/Keywords

Tags: sql, oracle, join

When querying an Oracle DB:

If the query is a select with joins, does the syntax have to include the keywords:

- INNER JOIN
- OUTER JOIN
- LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN

If not, then what are the alternative usages/syntax?

I ask this because I am looking at a SELECT statement that does not use any of the JOIN keywords within the FROM clause, but includes the joining syntax within the WHERE clause, and I am wondering:

- **if the select is executing a JOIN**
- **if so, what kind of JOIN is it querying**?

Example:

```
SELECT e.name, e.employeeid, d.sales, d.task, sum(d.hours)
FROM employee e,
       timecard d,
WHERE e.employeeid = d.employeeid and
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Read about ANSI Joins - http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ansi-iso-sql-support.php

Comment: The ANSI standard is to use JOIN..The older style is FROM a,b WHERE a.x=b.y

Comment: @Mihai: implicit joins in the `where` clause are ANSI joins as well. The explicit `JOIN` syntax was introduced with SQL-92, the implicit one with SQL-89

Comment: totally forgot its called "Implicit" blahblah.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a (inner) join, and could be rewritten as

```
SELECT e.name, e.employeeid, d.sales, d.task, sum(d.hours)
FROM employee e
JOIN timecard d on e.employeeid = d.employeeid
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: This is *not* a full join.  It is an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

That example is equivalent to an INNER JOIN.  The equivalent (deprecated) syntax in Oracle for a LEFT join would be

```
SELECT e.name, e.employeeid, d.sales, d.task, sum(d.hours)
FROM employee e,
       timecard d,
WHERE e.employeeid = d.employeeid(+) and
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```