# How to use the JOIN operator in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following relational schema of Academics:

```
ACADEMIC(acnum, deptnum*, famname, givename, initials, title)
PAPER(panum, title)
AUTHOR(panum*, acnum*)
```

I have been asked to return acnum, givename, famname and the total number of papers he/she has written for each academic.

I don't know how to make the connection between the tables.

```sql
SELECT academic.ACNUM, academic.GIVENAME, academic.FAMNAME
FROM paper,
     author,
     academic
WHERE author.PANUM = paper.PANUM
GROUP BY academic.ACNUM, academic.GIVENAME, academic.FAMNAME, count(author.PANUM = paper.PANUM);
```

Comment: Move the COUNT() from WHERE clause to the SELECT list

Comment: Does this question & answer help you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361071/oracle-sql-joins-syntax-keywords

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build SQL (Oracle Syntax) for Beginners, go through the following steps:

Make an Empty SQL Scheme

```
SELECT
FROM  
WHERE
GROUP BY
```

Fill in the Tables (with aliases) you need:

```
FROM paper    pap,
     author   aut,
     academic aca
```

Add Joins in WHERE Clause

```
FROM  paper    pap,
      author   aut,
      academic aca
WHERE aut.panum = pap.panum
AND   aut.acnum = aca.deptnum
```

Then Select the Columns you need

```
SELECT aca.acnum
      ,aca.givename
      ,aca.famname
      ,count (pap.title) as number_titles
FROM   paper    pap
      ,author   aut
      ,academic aca
WHERE  aut.panum = pap.panum
AND    aut.acnum = aca.acnum
```

As you want to count something, add GROUP BY

```
SELECT aca.acnum
      ,aca.givename
      ,aca.famname
      ,count (pap.title) as number_titles
FROM   paper    pap
      ,author   aut
      ,academic aca
WHERE  aut.panum = pap.panum
AND    aut.acnum = aca.acnum
GROUP  BY aca.acnum
         ,aca.givename
         ,aca.famname
```

And here we go. Above is the Oracle Syntas, below is ANSI SQL which does the work as good:

```
SELECT aca.acnum
      ,aca.givename
      ,aca.famname
      ,count (pap.title) as number_titles
FROM       paper    pap
INNER JOIN author   aut ON aut.panum = pap.panum
INNER JOIN academic aca ON aut.acnum = aca.acnum
GROUP  BY aca.acnum
         ,aca.givename
         ,aca.famname
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work-

```
SELECT AC.ACNUM, AC.GIVENAME, AC.FAMNAME,COUNT(*)
FROM paper P
INNER JOIN author A ON P.panum = A.panum
INNER JOIN ACADEMIC AC ON A.acnum = AC.acnum
GROUP BY  AC.ACNUM, AC.GIVENAME, AC.FAMNAME
```